# How to retrieve the account id just created with nested methods?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, methods, associations

I am using Ruby on Rails 3 and I successfully use nested models in order to save model\object associations.

In the user model file I have:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :account

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :account
  validates_associated :account
end
```

After `@user.save` *I would like to retrieve the account id just created and save that value in the user database table*. I need that because I will use the `account_id` as the foreign key for the user class, but I don't know if it is possible. If so, **how can I do that?**

---

In my user model I also tryed the following:

```
before_create :initialize_user

def initialize_user
  user_account = Account.create
  self.account_id = user_account.id
end
```

but it doesn't work.

---

**UPDATE**

I tryed this

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :account,
    :class_name  => "Account",
    :foreign_key => "users_account_id"
end

class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :user,
    :class_name  => "User",
    :foreign_key => "users_account_id"
end
```

and it save the new account. Anyway in the user database table the column `users_account_id` is `null` and so the foreign_key value isn't saved automatically.

Comment: `@user.account.id` doesn't work?

Comment: using has_... typically means that that model will have the primary key.  any model which belongs_to will typically contain the foreign key.  have you given though to doing 'belongs_to' in the account model to maintain the relationship?

Comment: @mway I think that I have to use that mainly in the controller. Maybe in the model I have to use a callback, but is it possible that if another person will create his own user, that person will get the same account.id value?(!) Anyway, I would like to find some "direct way".

Comment: @Will Ayd Whoops - yes, you're totally right, @user.account.id could potentially perform unnecessary lookups.  @user502052 - are you sure that the relationship is being saved properly?  IIRC models in Rails autoupdate so there is no need to actually fetch any more information; it should just be available.  May have changed in v3.x though.

Comment: @mway said: "Are you sure that the relationship is being saved properly?" - Yes, the account is stored properly in the database.

Comment: @mway, @Will Ayd - I updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

The Approach is wrong. When you have a "has_one" relationship, they foreign key is in the associated model. So in your case it will in account. And if its accepting nested attributes for account. That should be taken care of by default if you are doing it write.

Take a look http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1 and the other part as well, to see how nested forms work

Comment: I already seen that railscast, but I would like to have the key in the user model. So I should change the association from 'has_one' to 'belogns_to'?

Comment: @user502052 are you sure you dont want an account model that has_many users, and a user model which belongs_to an account?

Comment: yeh, change it to belongs_to, and when you accept nested attributes, it should just create the account itself. you don't have to create it separately.

Comment: @Will Ayd - No, I would like to have an User that has one account and an account that belongs to one User.

Comment: I updated the question as you said, but also that approach doesn't wirk ad expected.

Answer (score 0):

```
def initialize_user
  user_account = Account.create
  self.account_id = user_account.id
end
```

should be

```
def initialize_user
  self.account.create
end
```

When the new Account instance is being created, it will use the information about the current user automatically. Your method would have worked, but you'd have needed to add an extra "save" call.

Comment: I have also to pass parameters for the account filled from a form... so, using that, I don't if it is possible.

Comment: You can either add an extra argument to this 'initialize_user' utility function, or just call something like '@current_user.account.create params[:account_stuff]' from your controller.